# Can someone explain what this notation means, I cant quite figure out what is on the right side of the equation I've attached below

Tags: probability-theory

I know what the union and intersection is, it's just the way they're written together here that's confusing me
[image]

Comment: You can evaluate out-to-in what everything on the RHS means, and the end result is that $x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k\Leftrightarrow \forall n\ge 1,\exists k\ge n, x\in A_k$.

Comment: As long as you know what union and intersection notations mean, I'm afraid this means just what it says. You should elaborate on your confusion. Do you mean to ask, what is the *intuition* for this, instead of what it its exact meaning?